# Список элементов в YACC

Tags: грамматика, yacc

Для одной простенькой задачи захотел воспользоваться YACC'ом (сразу - bison и прочее просьба не предлагать, мне для микрограмматики YACC'а выше крыши, а учить новое просто так не хочется).

Запнулся на такой вещи - нужен список элементов, что-то типа

```
item ; item ; item
```

Элементарно -

```
list : list ';' item
     | item
```

Но захотелось обрабатывать и список, в котором может быть последняя точка с запятой, но что-то в мозгах переклинило, никак не соображу, как разрешить и то, и другое.

```
list : list ';' item
     | item
     | item ';'
```

разрешает наличие пустого элемента - двух точек с запятой подряд. Опять не идеально :)

Для моего решения это вопрос непринципиальный, мне и так сойдет, но чувствую себя дураком :) Должно быть что-то в стиле "как я сам не дотумкал", но что?..

Comment: может промежуточный нетерминал ввести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list: list1
    | list1 ';'
list1 : list1 ';' item
      | item
```

[ещё пример](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf) элемент `initializer_list`

Comment: Воистину, "как я сам недотумкал" :) Спасибо!